# Sentence analysis trouble

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, to-infinitive

I need to make an analysis of this sentence:

> ....and we can use them to help you to buy the best product.

or

> ....and we can use them to help you buy the best product.

We - `subject`,
can use - `verbs`, them - `indirect subject`, to help you buy the best product - `direct subject`.

Am I right?

I'm not sure if to use `to buy` or just `buy` and if it is the part of subject or another sentence.

Comment: So that last part, is it the direct object?

Comment: @trenccan Please see my answer for a full analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Them* is the direct object of the verb 'use'. *To help you (to) buy the best product* is a non-finite clause functioning as a 'catenative complement'. This catenative complement is licensed (allowed) by the catenative verb 'use'.

Direct objects normally answer the question 'what'.<sup>*</sup> But *To help you (to) buy the best product* clearly does not answer the question of 'what do we use?'

It's called 'catenative' because of it's ability to form chains in a catenative construction. <sup>†</sup>

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/directobject.htm</sub>

<sup>†</sup> <sub>https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb</sub>

Answer (score 5):

> *....and we [can [use them [to help you [buy the best product]]]]*.

No, you've got the analysis mostly wrong.

This is a complex catenative construction with a number of catenative verbs, two intervening nouns as objects, and two catenative complement clauses.

"Can" is a catenative verb and the non-finite clause "use them to help you buy the best product" is its catenative complement.

"Use" is a catenative verb, "them" is its direct object, and the non-finite clause "to help you buy the best product" is a catenative complement of "use".

Likewise, "help" is a catenative verb with "you" as its direct object and the non-finite clause "buy the best product" is catenative complement of "help". Finally, "the best product" is direct object of "buy".

I've bracketed the catenative complement clauses.

Comment: In the sentence: I would like to go to the United States - is like to go also catenative construction?

Comment: @trenccan Yes: "like" is a catenative verb, and the non-finite clause "to go to the US" is its catenative complement.